# Materialize DatePicker overwrites jQuery DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, materialize

I use Materialize CSS as my CSS Framework, but I need to use jQuery UI datepicker specifically, so I wrote this one line in my js file :

```
$('#search_immobilier_date_debut').datepicker();
```

My issue is that Materialize uses the same jQuery function to instantiate its datepicker, which I don't want.

Even when I call Material JS right before jQuery UI JS, I still get the Materialize datepicker.

Here are my css files :

```
   <!-- Materialize CSS-CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
        <!-- jQuery UI CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("assets/styles-scripts/css/app.css") }}"/>
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Here are my JS files :

```
<!-- jQuery 3.3 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Materialize CSS-JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script src="{{ asset("assets/styles-scripts/js/app.js") }}"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all please don't link to materialize .css and .js files via CDN.
You should get Materialize project and include it to your project to access `init.js`file and also link to Materilize .js and .css files that exist in project. After that open `init.js` from this path in your project :

```
materialize\docs\js\init.js
```

Find below line in the file and comment it :

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

This causes Materialize Datepicker being unavailable.

Comment: Good solution, but via CDN's there's no way out ?

Comment: In my opinion easiest way is changing init.js file. also you can save CDN's in your local and find a way to disable datepicker. but if you want to have both link to CDN's directly and disable datepicker, you should find a way to override CDN and it's difficult. I don't know exactly how it can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else runs into this, Materialize version 1 no longer requires jQuery to instantiate. The best thing to do in this case is to make sure you are using the most recent version and follow the example given [in their docs](https://materializecss.com/pickers.html):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
  var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
});
```